# Both if and else conditions are executed

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

i am working on windows forms. I am facing very weird problem.

In one of button event handler, i have applied if and else condition.

The problem is both if condition and else condtion are executed.

Can somebody point where am i wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true && checkEbayName(textBox1.Text) == true )
            {
                DataSet ds = GetUserByEbayName(textBox1.Text);
                if (ds == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];

            }

            if (radioButton2.Checked == true && checkName(textBox1.Text) == true)
            {
                DataSet ds = GetUserByName(textBox1.Text);
                //if (checkCustomer(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text) == true)
                //{
                if (ds == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Customer with matching details");
            }

        }
```

Comment: From what I can see, your if/else is coded correctly (no bracket-problem or similar). Only solution then would be that your function is called 2x, where the radioButton is in a different state.

Comment: Your two if statements are not mutually excusive. Did you mean to use 'else if' instead of the second if statement?

Comment: I think you wanted to do `if (Radio1), elseif(Radio2), else`, but you've written `if(Radio1), if(Radio2), else`, which means that else will be executed if `Radio2 == false`, but `Radio1` can still be true; hence, `if(Radio1)` and `else` will both be executed.

Comment: the `if statement` is correct but something's not right from the OP `radioButton`.

Comment: You need to run in debug mode with break points. You would have seen how this happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your else will be fired if the first `if` is not executed. I suspect you want to use `else if` for your second `if`.

As your code stands the first `if` may evaluate as true. The logic will then fall into the second `if`. If that condition is not met the `else` will execute.

Comment: But when i run application, if is executed followed by else

Comment: @AmritSharma Are you saying your second `if` was executed as well as the `else`. Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a return statement inside first if?

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true && checkEbayName(textBox1.Text) == true )
{
    DataSet ds = GetUserByEbayName(textBox1.Text);
   if (ds == null)
   {
        return;
   }

   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `radiobutton1` is checked you execute the first condition and if `ds is not null` your code doesn't return but checks for the second if. This, if the two radiobuttons are mutually exclusive, cannot be true and the else is executed.

If you want to show a message box if there are no customer for you grid, you could rewrite your code to check for null ds at the end

```
DataSet ds = null;
if (radioButton1.Checked == true && checkEbayName(textBox1.Text) == true )
{
    ds = GetUserByEbayName(textBox1.Text);
    if (ds != null)
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true && checkName(textBox1.Text) == true)
{
    ds = GetUserByName(textBox1.Text);
    if (ds != null)
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
}

// Show the user that we have not found customers not by ebayname or username
if(ds == null)
    MessageBox.Show("No Customer with matching details");
```

Comment: Its possible the 2 radioButton will equals to true in the same control?

Comment: In two different groupboxes

Comment: i think we dont need the `else if` here. if the `radioButton` in the same control. but the question is not telling where was the `radioButton` is. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

An else will never be executed if the condition for the matching if is met. However you have to separate if's and the second is not depending on the first. A simplified version of your code would be

```
if(a){
   if(d) {
      return;
   }
}

if(b){}
else{
}
```

In the case where either a or d is false the execution will get to the second if. If b is also false then the else will be executed.

If you intended the else to be executed only in the case where both a and b are false then you will have to do as follows

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true && checkEbayName(textBox1.Text) == true ) {
 //...

} else if (radioButton2.Checked == true && checkName(textBox1.Text) == true) {
  //...
} else {
            MessageBox.Show("No Customer with matching details");
}
```